# Error while decoding xml. "&" not valid marker. Waiting ";"

Tags: c#, xmlexception

I have a xml file, when I'm trying to decode it.

```
                XmlElement cmd = data.DocumentElement;
                cmd.InnerXml = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(cmd.InnerXml);
```

I getting an error "&" is not valid marker. Waiting ";".
Xml file

```
<command type="Order" TZ="180">
<Detail InquiryNo="11100433067" InquiryLineNo="10000" LineNo="80000" ProductNo="1162" ProductName="Код товарной номенклатуры" Size="" Quantity="1" Amount="0" ValuatedAmount="0" Discount="0" CouponCode="20000" Color="" Status="0" Service="0" ExternalBarcode="" Barcode="7500277733715" Type="73" Keep="0" VAT_Rate="0" VAT_Amount="0" ItemNote="5408 03613959805885 8HNp&amp;ie&amp;ZX&quot;E"/>
<Detail InquiryNo="11100433067" InquiryLineNo="10000" LineNo="100000" ProductNo="1162" ProductName="Код товарной номенклатуры" Size="" Quantity="1" Amount="0" ValuatedAmount="0" Discount="0" CouponCode="30000" Color="" Status="0" Service="0" ExternalBarcode="" Barcode="7500277733715" Type="73" Keep="0" VAT_Rate="0" VAT_Amount="0" ItemNote="5408 03614850354540 9BTEXm*GsbOT*"/>
<Detail InquiryNo="11100433067" InquiryLineNo="10000" LineNo="120000" ProductNo="1162" ProductName="Код товарной номенклатуры" Size="" Quantity="1" Amount="0" ValuatedAmount="0" Discount="0" CouponCode="40000" Color="" Status="0" Service="0" ExternalBarcode="" Barcode="7500277733715" Type="73" Keep="0" VAT_Rate="0" VAT_Amount="0" ItemNote="5408 03613959805960 cp&lt;=U8&amp;5FY&quot;K"/>
<Detail InquiryNo="11100433067" InquiryLineNo="10000" LineNo="130000" ProductNo="1212" ProductName="Признак предмета расчета" Size="" Quantity="1" Amount="0" ValuatedAmount="0" Discount="0" CouponCode="40000" Color="" Status="0" Service="0" ExternalBarcode="" Barcode="7500277733715" Type="73" Keep="0" VAT_Rate="0" VAT_Amount="0" ItemNote="1"/>
<Detail InquiryNo="11100433067" InquiryLineNo="10000" LineNo="140000" ProductNo="1162" ProductName="Код товарной номенклатуры" Size="" Quantity="1" Amount="0" ValuatedAmount="0" Discount="0" CouponCode="50000" Color="" Status="0" Service="0" ExternalBarcode="" Barcode="7500277733715" Type="73" Keep="0" VAT_Rate="0" VAT_Amount="0" ItemNote="5408 03613959805885 -./;:&lt;=&gt;?/YTR"/>
</command>
```

Comment: The HtmlDecode replaces the `&amp;` with a plain `&` - making it invalid XML Why did you think you needed to decode it?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your XML contains an "&" which might cause problems. There should be `&amp;` written in the XML instead.

For future reference, in these scenarios it would be much easier to help if you provided (at least partially) the XML you're trying to parse.

Comment: Xml contains &amp; and other xml notations; ItemNote="5408 03613959805885 8HNp&amp;ie&amp;ZX&quot;E"/>